# Can transaction hash be used to get v, r, s parameters using web3js?

Tags: web3js, ecdsa

I am trying to create a function which can be used to get the v, r, s parameters (ECDSA) of the signature.
So i am thinking to pass a random tx hash from etherscan and it will return v,r,s parameters of the signed tx.

Can somebody please help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems both web3.js [v0.20](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransaction) and [v1.0](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#gettransaction) will strip r, s, v parameters.

But if you use the [JSON RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_gettransactionbyhash) directly it return those values.

In the wiki https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_gettransactionbyhash they gave an example using curl:

```
// Request
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionByHash","params":["0x88df016429689c079f3b2f6ad39fa052532c56795b733da78a91ebe6a713944b"],"id":1}'

// Result
{
    ... // some other data

    "v":"0x25", // 37
    "r":"0x1b5e176d927f8e9ab405058b2d2457392da3e20f328b16ddabcebc33eaac5fea",
    "s":"0x4ba69724e8f69de52f0125ad8b3c5c2cef33019bac3249e2c0a2192766d1721c"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use the raw tx hash from etherscan you can get the `v,r,s`. for this raw tx example:

```
0xf86c01850c4b201000825208949cbfd6ebdb9cfcccd6b043f43e524583486d455e880490283b23ec8f768025a067da959a6d114d42016b5fb43ff8ae018efe6e4c784d40dfb2f2aad8fb2d4f6ca00b019b1e457b592e5bfd553e3b73742de625c7b65145494a57dbca17e5e9d842
```

in that hash, look for "a0".

0xf86c01850c4b201000825208949cbfd6ebdb9cfcccd6b043f43e524583486d455e880490283b23ec8f768025
a067da959a6d114d42016b5fb43ff8ae018efe6e4c784d40dfb2f2aad8fb2d4f6c
a00b019b1e457b592e5bfd553e3b73742de625c7b65145494a57dbca17e5e9d842

1 byte, 2 chars before first "a0" is the `v` value:

```
  v=25
```

32 bytes after first "a0" is the `r` value

```
     a0 =160
     0x80=128

     a0-0x80=160-128=32 bytes

 r=67da959a6d114d42016b5fb43ff8ae018efe6e4c784d40dfb2f2aad8fb2d4f6c
```

32 bytes after second "a0" is the `s` value

```
s=0b019b1e457b592e5bfd553e3b73742de625c7b65145494a57dbca17e5e9d842
```